# Is there a way to record system sound with MediaRecorder in android?

Tags: java, android, audio, mediarecorder, mediaprojection

I have a media recorder, and i want to take screen capture without mic audio, only with the system sound.
Is there some solution to disable my mic and to capture system sounds?

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.NEED_SYSTEM_AUDIO_RESOURCE_HERE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. By Design mediarecorder took as audiosource only the predefined ones as per [instruction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setAudioSource(int)).